# How to use distinct() using typeorm in jsonB column?

Tags: postgresql, distinct, typeorm

I have a jsonB column, which I want to select originalData.item_id, and find the row with unique item_id. I am using typeOrm for query. Using ale inside query builder work perfect.

```js
   const boxPreviewActivities = await this.activityLogEntryRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('ale')
      .select(
        `DISTINCT ON (itemId) ale.*, ale."originalData"->'source'->>'item_id' as itemId`
      )LogEntry."originalData"->'source'->>'item_id' as itemId`
      )
```

But when I want to use my real table name activityLogEntry it does not work.

```js
  const boxPreviewActivities = await this.activityLogEntryRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('activityLogEntry')
      .select(
        `DISTINCT ON (itemId) activityLogEntry.*, activityLogEntry->'source'->>'item_id' as itemId`
      )
```

I want to attach the error also.

```js
[ExceptionsHandler] missing FROM-clause entry for table "activitylogentry"
```

What does this error mean ? Or am I using distinct in typeOrm in right way ?

Comment: Sounds like a case sensitivity issue. Try adding quotes around `"activityLogEntry".*` and `"activityLogEntry"->…`, or using a lowercase `createQueryBuilder('activitylogentry')`

Comment: @Bergi I used it by but not work. I think DISTINCT ON can not be using inside typeorm select. Instead I used distinctedOn method worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is working with **distinctOn** method from typeorm. TypeOrm select method not support DISTINCT ON from postgreSQL.

This is working snippet

```js
  const boxPreviewActivities = await this.activityLogEntryRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('activityLogEntry')
      .distinctOn([
        "activityLogEntry.originalData ::jsonb -> 'source' ->> 'item_id' ",
      ])
```